# jquery select preceding element

Tags: jquery

Following HTML-Dom:

```
<a href="#"><img src="..." alt="" /></a>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

How can I select the img-element when the div is the starting point?

```
$('.myClass') // with .prev() I was not successfull...
```

Thx in advance!
sl3dg3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$('.myClass').prev().find("img");
```

or you can use `.children` selector also

```
$('.myClass').prev().children("img");
```